# display all column with one column masked

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have two columns - name and ccNumber. I want to display both the column with one of them masked.

This query is showing only one column but I want all column to be displayed:

```
declare @t table (card_no varchar(20))
insert into @t
select ccNUMBER from ccinfo 
select 'XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-'+ substring(card_no, 13, 4) as card_no from @t
```

[i want name column with ccnumber column to be  masked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swwp5.png)

Comment: Need more relevant information

Comment: i have 2 columns in my tabel the above code only mask and display one columns , i want to display all columns with ccNumber column maked

Comment: Kindly provide sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below

```
declare @t table (name varchar(100),card_no varchar(20))
insert into @t
select name, ccNUMBER from ccinfo 
select name, 'XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-'+ substring(card_no, 13, 4) as card_no from @t
```

Answer (score 0):

check the following example. i think you need concatenation of columns.

```
create table demo

(
   firstName varchar(30),
    secondName varchar(30)
);

 insert into demo
 values
  ('soumyajit', 'chatterjee'),
  ('papai', 'chatterjee'),
  ('virat', 'kohli');


  select concat(firstName, ' ', secondName)as Name from demo;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the second column, too:

```
declare @t table (card_no varchar(20), name varchar(64));

insert into @t
select ccNUMBER, name from ccinfo 

select 'XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-'+ substring(card_no, 13, 4) as card_no, name from @t
```

or just use the original table:

```
select 'XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-'+ substring(ccNUMBER, 13, 4) as card_no, name from ccinfo
```